# How to initialise Drizzle ORM client with schema?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, schema, drizzle

I have an entity

```
// schema.ts
export const users = pgTable('users', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  email: varchar('email', {length: 256}).notNull(),
});
```

And then I'm trying to initialize the drizzle client

```
// db.server.ts
import {PostgresJsDatabase, drizzle} from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import postgres from 'postgres';
import * as schema from './schema';

const queryClient = postgres("postgres://...");
const db: PostgresJsDatabase = drizzle(queryClient, {schema});
```

Where VS Code starts to complain about the {schema} part with the following error:

```
Type 'PostgresJsDatabase<typeof import("/app/db/schema")>' is not assignable to type 'PostgresJsDatabase'.
  The types of '_.schema' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'ExtractTablesWithRelations<typeof import(/app/db/schema")> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ExtractTablesWithRelations<Record<string, never>> | undefined'.
      Type 'ExtractTablesWithRelations<typeof import("/app/db/schema")>' is not assignable to type 'ExtractTablesWithRelations<Record<string, never>>'.
        Property 'users' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type '{ tsName: "users"; dbName: "users"; columns: { id: PgColumn<{ name: "id"; tableName: "users"; dataType: "number"; columnType: "PgSerial"; data: number; driverParam: number; notNull: true; hasDefault: true; enumValues: undefined; baseColumn: never; }, {}, {}>; email: PgColumn<...>; }; relations: never; primaryKey: An...' is not assignable to type '{ tsName: string; dbName: never; columns: never; relations: Record<string, Relation<string>>; primaryKey: AnyColumn[]; }'.
            Types of property 'dbName' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

I've never been friends with Typescript (I'm still trying) so I have no clue what's wrong. This is how they do it in the examples... any tips?

This works just fine if I leave the `{schema}` part out, but I guess I need it form me to use the `db.query.users.findMany()` syntax, which I'd like to use?

Comment: Oh dear. When I removed the _PostgresJsDatabase_ casting from the drizzle initialization line, all problems went away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casting of the `db` const is wrong. It narrows down the result. So dropping the `PostgresJsDatabase` cast fixes the problem.